# How to get the current response length from a http.ResponseWriter

Tags: go

Given a `http.ResponseWriter` that has had some number of `.Write()`s done to it, can the current accumulated length of the response be obtained directly?

I'm pretty sure this could be done with a `Hijack` conversion, but I'd like to know if it can be done directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even if you'd know what you get, underlying the `http.ResponseWriter` interface, the chances are low, that there is something usable. If you [look closer](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#L110) at the struct you get using the standard `ServeHTTP` of the http package, you'll see that there's no way to get to the length of the buffer but hijacking it.

What you can do alternatively, is shadowing the writer:

```
type ResponseWriterWithLength struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    length int
}

func (w *ResponseWriterWithLength) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = w.ResponseWriter.Write(b)

    w.length += n

    return
}

func (w *ResponseWriterWithLength) Length() int {
    return w.length
}

func MyServant(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    lengthWriter := &ResponseWriterWithLength{w, 0}
}
```

You might even want to write your own version of `http.Server`, which serves the `ResponseWriterWithLength` by default.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was guessing. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: The only problem with that approach is that it doesn't take into account headers length.